# Information retrieval data collection

Tags: nlp, dataset, information-retrieval

I am looking for datasets designated for information retrieval. I found some datasets that are used for other NLP tasks like text categorization or sentiment analysis, but I haven't had any luck finding something specifically for information retrieval yet. Are there any places to look?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Google Dataset Search](https://toolbox.google.com/datasetsearch)?

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't even know that Google launched Dataset Search.

Answer (score 0):

Is this kind of datasets you're looking for?

http://www.daviddlewis.com/resources/testcollections/

http://boston.lti.cs.cmu.edu/callan/Data/

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for basic Information Retreival, check out the Glasgow IR Collection.

http://ir.dcs.gla.ac.uk/resources/test_collections/

Even though these datasets are very basic and old. They have **Relevance Judgements** which is beneficial in tasks to evaluate and rank.

TREC Collection is mainly for advanced IR tasks https://trec.nist.gov/